# Importing mail from another Zimbra server -- not all messages are imported in large folders

Tags: email, zimbra

I'm using zmmailbox to import a .tgz of a mailbox that was exported from another Zimbra server. It works for most mailboxes, but some mailboxes have large folders, and only some of the messages are imported. When I look in the tarball, all the messages are there, but they are in folders like Inbox!1, Inbox!2, etc. Is there a trick to get it to import all of the messages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at mailbox.log when this is triggered because it may not always be a timeout with large mailboxes, errs within the dump can also exit the import. From what I remember everything is logged into `/opt/zimbra/log/mailbox.log` and it is very detailed.  If in case `zmmailbox` doesn't help, I think taking a full backup of the account and restoring it to a new account with `zmrestore` can help. Just a wild thought.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this today, and am still looking for a workaround. For now, the only thing to do seems to be to write a script that would untar each file, match ones with the pattern `!d+`, copy the contents to the right folder and then tar everything back together again.